# Angular - <base href="/projectname/client"> in index.html throwing an error

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

My application is in Angular 7 deployed on Openshift with Docker image.
I want my application url to be like https://ocp-1123/projectname/client , when i tried to set my base href with "/projectname/client" it throws errors as in picture. [image]

But when I set my base href with "/projectname" or just "/" , it works perfectly fine. 
I am not sure if there is any restriction of usage of multiple path context in base href..? Please suggest .

Thank you.

Comment: I found the solution, I have removed the <scripts> tags in the index.html and added the corresponding npm packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an additional `/` in the end:

```
<base href="/projectname/client/">
```

as per the doc:

But on the shared or production server, you might serve the app from a subfolder. For example, when the URL to load the app is something like `http://example.com/my/app/`, the subfolder is `my/app/` and you should add `<base href="/my/app/">` to the server version of the index.html.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I tried this approach also but landing on the same error, it is unable to find the js files as shown in the picture in question.I even tried with- " ng build --base-href /projectname/client/ --deploy-url /projectname/client/ "

Answer (score 0):

Use `APP_BASE_HREF` key provider: Add this provider

```js
{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/projectname/client' }
```

to `AppModule` providers.